# Wire for old device

Tags: usb

First off my apologies if this in the wrong forum, I'm not quite sure where to post this. My boss is asking me to pull data (if possible) from the device in the picture below but I have no idea what wire goes into this. Perhaps one that could connect to a USB? I was hoping someone here would know what it's called and/or have any info about it. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I tried an 8 pin mini din and it did not work.

Comment: Looks like a mini-Din 8 but you said it won't work so I'm not sure why. You may seek for help on [su] though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data from this controller you will need one of these cables:

[Amazon -serial port](https://www.amazon.ca/Replacement-Bradley-Micrologix-Programming-1761-CBL-PM02/dp/B07FK96F2Z/ref=pd_sbs_328_2/146-1801831-4991467?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07FK96F2Z&pd_rd_r=5167b084-1efc-46ef-bda7-4fb7bc33a622&pd_rd_w=NhG8g&pd_rd_wg=VaYPh&pf_rd_p=74b54c94-7195-4620-ba51-7d167ac58a58&pf_rd_r=T87VMJVTBVH1NA6RCC5P&psc=1&refRID=T87VMJVTBVH1NA6RCC5P)   ------------------------------------------------------------[USB- Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Bradley-Micrologix-Programming-USB-1761-CBL-PM02/dp/B007J2XQ6W)

[image][image]

And the software. The software you need will be called [RSLinx (Classic) Lite](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&client=firefox-b-d&ei=T0RFXsy6HsKp_Qbp0ZXQBg&q=rslinx%20classic%20lite&oq=rslinx%20classic%20lite&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l8j0i333l2.9329.15161..15309...0.2..0.117.884.8j2......0....2j1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i273j0i10.ha2fRlGKy7U&ved=0ahUKEwiMntjsxs7nAhXCVN8KHeloBWoQ4dUDCAo&uact=5). This is the only one that can connect physically to this device.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @CaldeiraG, it is an 8-Pin Mini-DIN. It is a comm port to connect to a device with a RS-232-C connection.

Here is a manual for a similar model of [MicroLogix 1000 series Controller](https://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/um/1761-um003_-en-p.pdf).

[image: 8-Pin Mini-DIN Male side]

P.S. Next time you post please include all available information. Cutting out the name of the device in question means more work from those that you are asking for help.